# How can I set query params in a url of django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, http-status-code-404, django-urls

I have an API that i need to remove something from cache of Redis
So I build a view and sync it to a url but I keep getting HTTP_404 (not found).

```
class ExpireRoom(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    def delete(self, request, format=None):
        room_manager = RoomManager()
        room_identifier = self.kwargs['room_identifier']
        is_success = room_manager.delete(room_identifier)
        if is_success:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

Here's my url in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^expire-room/(?P<room_identifier>\w+)/$', 
        ExpireRoom.as_view(),
        name='core_ExpireRoom_deletingRoom')
]
```

Comment: Could you provide an example request of yours with curl or anything?

Comment: Note that query parameters aren't part of the URL path, i.e. you don't need to pre-define them in the url patters. If you have a pattern for **/expire-room/** then **/expire-room/?myparam=hello&someotherparam=world** will just work and pass **myparam** and **someotherparam** to the `request.GET` dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what URL you are requesting, but your question's title suggests you're passing query parameters.

Query parameters aren't part of the URL path, i.e. you don't need to pre-define them in the url patters. If you have a pattern for **/expire-room/** then **/expire-room/?myparam=hello&someotherparam=world** will just work and pass **myparam** and **someotherparam** to the `request.GET` dictionary.

The URL pattern you defined will only match URLs starting with **/expire-room/some-room/** where `some-room` is any string.

Comment: Thanks for your response request.GET worked and i will use it. But anyway in the last paragraph you mentioned that URLs starting with /expire-room/some-room/ will work but it doesn't and it gives me a 404 not found.